# How can I produce a Kafka Record with null value using the kafka tool set

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using the following command:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test.topic --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=#
```

This allows me to start typing **key#value** entries.

However, no matter what I try, I'm not able to create a **null** entry.

If I try sending [myKey#] and press Enter, on the feed I will see an Empty message for the Key, but not null.

I need to create a Null value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Producing a Kafka message with a Null Value (Tombstone) from the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057588/producing-a-kafka-message-with-a-null-value-tombstone-from-the-console)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Console producer cannot produce a null record. It parses the input as UTF8 strings

Personally, I would write a simple python or ruby script to do so

Comment: Managed to write a small Java app to achieve this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `kafkacat` might also work. Can't remember right now

Comment: @Stole can you give me a hint how you wrote your java app? I cant seem to get mine to work with apache kafka producer.. 
stringProducer.send(
                ProducerRecord(statesTopic, key, null)
        )

Comment: @a.hrdie That should work fine https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringSerializer.java#L46

Answer (score 11):

[kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat) allows you to produce tombstones through the `-Z` option.

Produce a tombstone (a "delete" for compacted topics) for key "abc" by providing an empty message value which -Z interpretes as NULL:

`$ echo "abc:" | kafkacat -b mybroker -t mytopic -Z -K:`